# .htaccess URL Rewrite: Point directory name to filename

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Sorry if this question already asked here. But I could not found the solution yet.

I have the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I want to rewrite the URL from **domain.com/index.php?page=contact**  -To- **domain.com/contact**

Yes, it worked well. But the problem is when I add a **forward slash /** like this **domain.com/contact/**

It displayed **Not Found** page instead. I think the browser recognized  **contact/** as a directory but not a file.

I really want the visitor can access to that page by that two ways with forward slash / at the end and without it. How to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Make trailing slash optional in your regex in as `^([^/]+)/?$`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.